# How does a gauge theory probe a spacetime singularity?

Tags: string-theory, quantum-gravity, gauge-theory, singularities

Within the framework of string theory, I have read in numerous articles such as the introduction of [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1305.3607) in which it is stated that the gauge theories living on a stack of D-branes can be used to *probe a spacetime singularity*, such as for example a [Calabi-Yau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calabi%E2%80%93Yau_manifold) or [toric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toric_variety) one.

What is exactly meant by that?

Answer (score 4):

Probing just means that the objects known as probes – D-branes in this case – are placed in an external geometry or other conditions and this external geometry or conditions (in your case singular geometry) affects the internal dynamics of the probe. The terms living in the world volume of the probe are affected by the environment – to some extent, the change looks "just like" the would-be objective geometry that could be studied by other "apparatuses", but it may also differ substantially. One probe may see the geometry as singular, another one may see it as non-singular (the probe's Lagrangian depends smoothly on the coordinates of its points etc.).